# Restricting access to Microsoft Graph based on IP address, using application level auth and multi-tenanted app

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to access data from a variety of tenants' ADs. This is with a multitenanted Azure app hosted in my Azure tenancy. Authentication is handled using application level tokens and the client credentials flow; customer admins authorize the collection of data for their tenancy using OAuth. A customer is asking whether it's possible for me to restrict access to my Azure app based on location, so that our app dispenses tokens only to clients who are inside our data center.

**It seems to me that this is not going to work**. Microsoft recently added the possibility of conditional access based on workload identities; but are pretty clear that this only works for single-tenant apps, where the same tenancy hosts both the enterprise application and the app registration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/workload-identity

> Note
>
> Policy can be applied to single tenant service principals that have
> been registered in your tenant. Third party SaaS and multi-tenanted
> apps are out of scope. Managed identities are not covered by policy.

But, I am not an expert and may be working on incorrect assumptions. Can anyone confirm or disconfirm what I have posted here? Is there some way I can provide what the customer is asking for?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the document that it is applicable only to the single tenants, If you want this feature to be available for the mutlti tenants as well you can raise a feature request for same here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Comment: Cheers Mehtab! I do accept your answer but am leaving the question open in case anyone has any ideas how else I can accomplish the goal of restricting access to my Azure app by IP range.